# How can I apply something like 'subtr' to cut a string with (...) in Meteor js?

Tags: javascript

In PHP we have functions to cut long texts, to make a kind of 'preview' by stoping the whole result with the subrt() function in order to put a limit to the string.

Is there any way of do the same but in JavaScript?

what I need is to show

blablablabla...

instead of blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla (the whole text) when showing results {{mytext}}

Comment: You might also be interested in using simple CSS rules, like [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively straight forward function to write in javascript. 
[Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is a function in javascript with the signature `str.substring(startIndex, [endIndex])`. So if you wanted to take the first `n` characters from a string and then append an ellipses you could do the following

```
// verbose
function shorten(str, n) {
    var chopped = str.substr(0, n);
    var formatted = chopped + '...';
    return formatted;

}
// one liner
function shorten(str, n) {
    return str.substr(0, n) + '...';
}
// shorten('foobarbatbaz', 3) -> 'foo...'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about meteor, but javscript itself has a `substr` function for strings, `<string>.substr(<length>)` for instance `"asdf123123123123123".substr(4)`  gives you <strike>`"asdf"`</strike>
EDIT: it gives you "123123123123123", I was thinking of `substr(0,4)`

Comment: Almost. That would give you `123123123123123`. Did you mean `.substr(0,4)`?